# Retrieving the keys value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the value of the key from the api response. my code looks like

```
if(response[0].status == "Success")
            {
                alert('success');
            }
            else
            {
                var texts = "";
                for (reasons in response[0].error_reason) {
                    texts += reasons+";";
            }
                alert(texts);
            }
```

My key here is "item" and its value is "Choose an valid item" . i want to print the value in alert. BUt when i try to alert its displaying the key(item) not the value. how can i display key value here. also there can be multiple keys like items.

Comment: You can try: `texts += response[0].error_reason[reasons] + ";";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, the `foreach` loop in JavaScript iterates through keys, that means that the `reasons` variable in your code will be set to a new key after each iteration. In order to access the value, you simply use the `reasons` variable as the index like this:

```
var texts = "";
for (reasons in response[0].error_reason) {
    texts += reasons + " = " + response[0].error_reason[reasons] +";";
}
```

However, you should be careful with `foreach` in Javascript, because it iterates through *all* the properties of an object, including the functions of the object's prototype, e.g. you will get `indexOf` as a key in your loop eventually. To avoid that, you should check the value's type:

```
var texts = "";
for (reasons in response[0].error_reason) 
    if(typeof(response[0].error_reason[reasons]) !== 'function')
        texts += reasons + " = " + response[0].error_reason[reasons] +";";
```

This should work as intended.